# Retrieving value from nested div through selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have the following HTML page

```
<div class="Test_cWidgetContainer" id="479b9c05-3f2b-43a1-c24d-89f574673326" draggable="false" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-size: 100% 100%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 15px; width: 159px; height: 31px; z-index: 8; font-size: 0px;">
<div style="text-align: center; display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;">
   <div style="display: inline-block; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 9px; line-height: normal; font-family: TestDefault, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(70, 70, 70);">FIC636130682944873438 - 1</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have written the following piece of code to display the text output FIC636...

```
IWebElement element =  driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("Test_cWidgetContainer"));

String labelText = element.Text
Console.WriteLine(labelText);
```

But the **labelText** does not display any value? Can someone help me with what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the text present under Inner `div` of element located by you. So you have to locate the inner `div` in this way using xpath

```
.//div[@class='Test_cWidgetContainer']/div/div/div
```

In your code :

```
IWebElement element =  driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[@class='Test_cWidgetContainer']/div/div/div"));

String labelText = element.Text
Console.WriteLine(labelText);
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I handle if I do not know how many div nesting as this page is generated through custom controls on a different tool.

Comment: Is your text `FIC636130682944873438` always start with `FIC` or every time dynamic?

Comment: The text is always dynamic as this text comes from underlying DB and it can have multiple values.

Comment: Ok fine , can you please add  the html other then `.//div[@class='Test_cWidgetContainer']/div/div/div` this structure as you are saying you don't know how many nested `div` are there. So there might be change structure